# Left shift key unresponsive and stuck?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

Okay, so I have a mid-2010 MacBook Pro (unibody design) and I have the typical problem with the keyboard. My shift key function is "stuck" so everything WILL COME UP LIKE THIS> (hence the > instead of the period). I booted into a flash drive to update to Lion and the keyboard still typed like the shift key was pressed. Well, we went to Apple to see what they could do. They said that the top case has to be replaced. The problem is, that runs a whopping $250+ and that's out of my budget right now. I have been searching around and haven't seemed to find much of a solution anywhere. I have seen that (at least on here) that the keyboard itself can be replaced without having to replace the entire top case. Nothing has been spilled onto the keyboard and it is not dirty as I have taken a few keys off and checked underneath. So if I replaced the keyboard only, would that fix the problem? Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tell application "System Events"
        key up {shift}
end tell
```

via `osascript`.

Comment: I used the "on-screen keyboard" that allows you to click the key and disengage it. I decided to just disable the key with some third party software. I disabled the left shift key and everything works normal besides the left shift key has no function anymore. Kind of a half-ass solution..

Comment: @BradKaufman You should post that as an answer and accept it. I know other people would be interested in what software you used to disable the key.